# bootstrap carousel showing total blank

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

Console is showing every element is where its supposed to be but the is just not showing anything, its like everything has gone under a white blanket,i never seen this kind of problem and have no clue what it might be. strange thing is not even images are showing up

here is the code   [bootstrap carousel](http://codepen.io/wahidpolin/pen/KdjYae)

```html
<!--read-anywhere starts -->
<section class="read-anywhere page" id="read-anywhere">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="main-heading clearfix">
        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <h1 class="text-center">Carousel</h1>
          <h2 class="text-center">Carousel sub title.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div id="read-anywhere-slider" class="carousel fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
          <div class="row">

            <!-- Indicators -->
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#read-anywhere-slider" data-slide-to="0" class="mobile active">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" width="30px"> mobile
                </li>
                <li data-target="#read-anywhere-slider" data-slide-to="1" class="kindle">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" width="35px"> kindle
                </li>
                <li data-target="#read-anywhere-slider" data-slide-to="2" class="tablet">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" width="35px"> tablet
                </li>
                <li data-target="#read-anywhere-slider" data-slide-to="3" class="laptop">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" width="45px"> laptop
                </li>
              </ol>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
              <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" class="read-ipad">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" class="read-laptop">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" class="read-iphone">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/500/" class="read-kindle">
                </div>

              </div>


            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!--read-anywhere ends -->
```

Comment: Have you included the bootstrap.js javascript file?

Comment: yes and also on my actual site there is one working bootstrap slider so idont see how anything can be missing

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML code contains a couple of mistakes.

Your current code looks like this (in Emmet style):

```
.col-md-12 > .carousel > .row > .col-md-6 + .col-md-6 > .carousel-inner
```

By the way, in this case you don't need `.col-md-12` at all.  So the final HTML structure will look this:

```
.container > .row > .col-md-6 + .col-md-6 > .carousel > .carousel inner
```

The second mistake is `.fade` class on `.carousel`. By default, bootstrap can't do fade animations for carousels. The `fade` class will work only with a modal component. Default carousel behaviour is sliding. So you need to add the `.slide` class to your `.carousel` element.

If you want to get fade effects, you can try someone's snippets like in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/Rowno/pen/Afykb).

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm not quite familiar with [carousel.js](/questions/tagged/carousel.js), but I changed this:

```
class="carousel fade"
```

into:

```
class="carousel slide"
```

And that makes at least the sliding pictures appear.

Comment: thank you man, i have used a custom 'fade' class in one of my other project,i copied the html from that project without including  the fade classes in my css.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check this `[jsfiddle][1]`

May be it's helpful to you